# Dynamically connect to different databases in springboot service

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot

I'm still a new developer and I'm working on something that will allow users to provide connection details to various databases (mysql, oracle, greenplum, etc) and it would test the connections and run a query. The details they would provide would be Hostname, database name, and port. I will have own defined username and password, so they won't need to provide that.

I've seen a lot of things on springboot that are predefining multiple connections within application.properties, but these are static. I'm trying connect to the database they point me to for them based on their input.

My simple question is, is this possible? If so, any guidance on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: only solution that I'm thinking of is manually setting up JDBC connection based on the input received.

Comment: Do you have any reference/guides/implementations you could point me to?

Comment: [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) might help you getting overall idea.

Comment: So looking at this, would I just based, on certain criteria, change values like the following

`static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  `
`static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";`

?

Comment: Yeah. But remember you have to manage the connection also. (Open and Close) to avoid connection leakage.

Comment: Okay - great! Thanks for your responses; I'm sure I'll have more as I go!!!

Comment: @JaisAnkit thank you for your input! This definitely got me started down the correct path, and now have a working solution! Thank you. If you'd like to set it as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: That's Great !! Please set it so that its useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments above. I used the suggested documentation for creating a JDBC application. This gave me the solid framework to build the rest of my applicaiton. Link is provided below;

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm